# Azure KeyVault key rotation

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

The [Azure Storage sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/tree/master/Samples/GettingStarted/EncryptionSamples/KeyRotation) for key rotation demonstrates using multiple uniquely named Secrets.  However, within KeyVault it is now possible to create multiple versions of a single Secret. I can see no reason why key rotation cannot be achieved using Versions and it seems on the face of it like it'd be easier to manage.

Can anyone offer any guidance on why you'd choose multiple Secrets over versions of a single Secret to support key rotation? And potentially any generally guidance on what Versions are intended for if not this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but looking at the API, it seems like each secret without a version identifier defaults to the latest version, and that's the intended approach. So mostly it looks like the APIs out there (REST, .NET, etc.) aren't really building code patterns to support using the versions as you intend.

Comment: For example, it looks like the ResolverKeyAsync method doesn't allow you to provide a version value to select different versions of a key. Maybe when the APIs have matured for this new functionality this pattern would make more sense. Again, not an expert, grain of salt, etc.

Comment: Thanks @kyle-hale.  In answer to your point "[..] looking at the API, it seems like each secret without a version identifier defaults to the latest version" - correct. But I don't think this matters (in fact I think it's desirable). Since each version of the key can be addressed uniquely, so long as the version is stored data encrypted with a previous version can be decrypted and the latest version used for encryption

Comment: My immediate thought is that they have used that approach in the samples because it is easier to follow, using versions would make the code a little less clear. in [other places](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-key-rotation-log-monitoring/) versioning appears to be the suggested approach

Comment: see - https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/334 - "We are working on improving the entire key rotation experience, and updating the sample to use Key Vault key versions is part of this effort."

Comment: @MichaelB awesome, thanks for that!

Comment: You're headed in the right direction... a lot of us are using KeyVault versioning just fine for this. I think the reason for 2 keys, even with versioned vaults, remains the ability to rotate keys without downtime across very large environments.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to use a single secret and multiple versions for key rotation, depending on which SDK(s) you are using.

For our Node.js-based apps, we have configuration that points at the full KeyVault secret URIs.

Some secrets only point at the short URL for a secret (no version), so the app gets "the latest version".

Other secrets that need rotation will need the full URL to the version. We use Azure Table Encryption, for example; so each row in the table when encrypted uses a key wrapping key from KeyVault. The key wrapping key is a full KeyVault versioned URL, since you need that specific secret to decrypt the table data. Over time, different rows will point at different key versions.

For general scenarios, i.e. rotating a current version of a key to a new one, just built your configuration system and connection logic to support 2 keys at a time - if one fails, use the other; or consider a time-based logic.

Any approach is fine, but consider how nice and "clean" your story will be if you use versions over time instead of proliferating additional secret names.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of versions a secret can have?